# Get the TThread object for the currently executing thread?

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I want a function like GetCurrentThread which returns a TThread object of the current executing thread. I know there is a Win32 API call GetCurrentThread, but it returns the thread Id. If there is a possibility to get TThread object from that ID that's also fine.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The latest version of Delphi, Delphi 2009, has a CurrentThread class property on the TThread class.

This will return the proper Delphi thread object if it's a native thread. If the thread is an "alien" thread, i.e. created using some other mechanism or on a callback from a third party thread, then it will create a wrapper thread around the thread handle.

Comment: Unfortunately, CurrentThread has a serious flaw rendering it useless: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188281/delphi-tthread-
currentthread-and-eaccessviolation-is-this-a-bug-or-my-incompete

Comment: @Roddy and for future readers: that was fixed with a patch in 2009 and fixed in the 2010 release.

Comment: @DavidM - Thanks - yes, fixed in D2010. D2009 requires the (unofficial) patch linked from the other question - none of the D2009 official updates address this issue.

Answer (score 25):

From your own answer, it seems maybe you only want to "determine if running in the main thread or not", in which case you can just use

```
if Windows.GetCurrentThreadId() = System.MainThreadID then
// ...
```

Although this won't work from a DLL created with Delphi if it was loaded by a worker thread.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using my own TThread descendent that registers itself in a global list, protected with a lock.

That way, a method in this descendent can walk the list and get a TThread give an ID.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. I guess it is not possible to get TThread object from ID. It is possible by using a global variable. Then comparing its handle and current thread id, one can determine if running in the main thread or not.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't the current executing thread be the one you're trying to run a function from?

Answer (score 0):

You could store the pointer of the TThread instance in the current thread's context via the *TlsSetValue* API call and then retrieve it using *TlsGetValue*. However, note that this will only work if you're trying to retrieve/store the TThread instance of the **current** thread.